# About Countable Dense Homogeneous spaces (CDH) and strongly locally homogeneous spaces

Tags: general-topology, homogeneous-spaces

I am new to the study of CDH topological spaces, I wanted to study basic examples of this type of spaces, for example I could understand the demonstration that $\mathbb{R}$ is CDH, using the Cantor method (back-and- forth). I have tried to imitate the idea of proof to demonstrate that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is CDH but I have not been successful, does anyone have any idea how to demonstrate this fact? I have found that other authors introduce the notion of Strongly Locally Homogeneous spaces, and show that "**If $X$ is Polish and strongly locally
homogeneous. Then $X$ is countable dense homogeneous**". Unfortunately I have also failed to demonstrate that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is strongly locally
homogeneous but also was not successful, does anyone have any ideas? Also, I would like to know what bibliography you recommend for a basic study of CDH spaces.

Thank you very much

Comment: It's quite easy to see that $\Bbb R^n$ is strongly locally homogeneous. You do know and understand the proof for Polish spaces?

Comment: *Open Problems in Topology* (van Mill, Reed, 1990) in chapter 15 has a survey with open problems regarding CDH. Start with the literature list of that, e.g.

Comment: Hi @Henno, unfortunately I don't know the proof for Polish spaces. In fact, I still can't prove that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is SLH? Do you know any reference for this last fact?